# How to set up test configuration in PhpStorm to use different interpreters

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I'm using `PhpStorm 2018.1.5` and I'd like to set up test configurations with 2 different interpreters.

The reason is I need one configuration with `xdebug` enabled (to run code coverage reports) and another configuration without `xdebug` to run ordinary tests without coverage.

My current configuration looks like this:

[image: Test configurations]

With interpreters defined like this:

[image: Interpreters]

And my debug configuration:

[image: Debug configuration]

There seems to be no way to select which interpreter I want to use for a test configuration.

Am I missing something or is this currently not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there's no way to choose local interpreter for run/debug configurations - please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35548.

As for now, there's an option to enable Xdebug on-demand - that looks like a perfect solution here. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#on_demand_mode for more details.